# TypeORM: how to use In() with @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have two entities: `Something` and `Other` (prototypes are below).

How can I use `In()` method to find all `Somethings` that have related `Others` by array of `Others` ids?

I need something like this:

```
const smths: Array<Something> = await connection.getRepository(Something).find({
    others: In(arrayWithOthersIds),
});
```

Entities:

```
@Entity()
class Something {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => Other, (other) => other.smths, { cascade: true })
    others: Other[];
}

@Entity()
class Other {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => Something, (smth) => smth.others, { cascade: true })
    smths: Something[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `@JoinTable()` from 1 side of your many-to-many relationship. Also as I know you can not use `{ cascade: true }` on both sides, so remove one. And use this query:

```js
const smths: Something[] = await connection
   .getRepository(Something)
   .createQueryBuilder('smth')
   .innerJoin("smth.others", "others")
   .where('others.id IN (:...ids)', { ids } ) // ids = [1, 2..]
   .getMany();
```